# authenticate to KeyCloak from a userless java application

Tags: java, keycloak

I have an application protected by KeyCloak.

I want to write a new service which will interact with this application. New service runs on JVM and does not have users, it must have it's own identity/permissions/etc but use the existing rest api.

All examples I saw of Java auth seem to be user/password base, or even open a browser. This is not suitable. Do I need to create a new "client" in KeyCloak and have a secret key for the client? How to use this in Java to authenticate?

Alternatively should I use the existing client and create a special user with an offline access token valid forever? Again how would I use this offline access token from Java to work with KeyCloak?

Comment: Use `Client Credentials Flow`, which is used for machine to machine communication.